# Jquery posting multiple select values

Tags: php, jquery, post, mysqli

The below code is working fine when you alert it (e.g. it will say "1,2" if Option's 1 and 2 are selected), but when I try to post it using jquery to a database, it simply outputs "Array". I've tried using toString on it, which I thought might help, but it doesn't seem to. The [plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) is working fine so I think it must be an error in the way I post it.

How can I get it to post to the database the selected values separated by commas (e.g."1,2") as it does when alerting, instead of "Array"?

HTML

```
<select id='category' class='category' multiple='multiple'>
    <option value='0'>Nothing</option>
    <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Run the plugin:

```
$(function(){
$(".category").multiselect();
});
```

Send to database:

```
$('.category').change(function() {
var selected = $(this).val();
alert(selected);
    $.post('update_db.php', {
    content : selected,
    id : <?php echo $getid;?>,
    set : "column_heading"
    })
});
```

update_db.php works for everything except this multiple selection.

```
$where = $_POST['id'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$set = $_POST['set'];
mysqli_query($my_db,"UPDATE my_table SET " . $set . "='" . $content . "' WHERE id=" . $where);
```

Comment: Most likely you are handling the data wrong in your PHP script.

Comment: What is the data type of the `column_heading` field in your DB?

Comment: The column is varchar

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you send your data to the server in the form of an array. When you cast an array to string in php, it will end up as the string `"Array"`.

If you have an array variable `$array`, and you append that to a string using the concatenate (put together) operator `.`, it might not do what you expect:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);
$foo = 'foo ' . $array; // 'foo Array'
```

The bigger problem here is that you are creating an SQL query using string concatenation, which leaves you open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should really consider using PDO or some other abstraction layer that allows for prepared queries, or use escaping.

Comment: -1: per code `id` is a single value set via PHP, it is `content` which has multiple values; `... SET column_heading='[1,2,3]' where id=...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried sending it to an update_db_pdo file which Posts the data the same way but uses PDO (and with the query as "UPDATE `my_table` SET `$set`='$content' WHERE `id`=$where";) but it didn't work (still outputs "Array"). Could this statement still be causing problems?

Comment: You may want to loop over `$content` using `foreach($content as $value)` and then use `$value` instead of `$content` in your query.